# Jasmine-gem / jasmine:ci : How to console.log?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, jasmine

I'm using the [jasmine-gem](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-gem) as part of a rails project.

I know I can run the tests in a browser with `rake jasmine`, but I need to run them headless via `rake jasmine:ci`.

When I'm running them in headless/ci mode, `console.log`s do not get outputted. How can I accomplish this? Maybe something in `jasmine_helper.rb` ?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out.

In `jasmine_helpers.rb`:

```
Jasmine.configure do |config|
  config.show_console_log = true
end
```

Comment: This `config` option was added in 2.x; in 1.x try using `jasmine.log` instead of `console.log`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by adding the following to your `jasmine.yml` file:

`show_console_log: true`